# Cant read UDP network stream in h264 from opencv4nodejs

Tags: node.js, opencv, udp, h.264, video-capture

i'm trying to get a video stream from a djy drone 'Tello' with nodejs. the UDP server is working because i can manually get the stream and show it on my mac with "ffplay udp://198.168.10.1:11111".

Anyway i cant make opencv4nodejs (porting of opencv) working while making const capture = new VideoCapture('udp://192.168.10.1:11111', cv.CAP_FFMPEG).

Construction of object 'capture' fails with this message:
'OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "udp://192.168.10.1:11111"'

P.S: if I use const capture = new VideCapture(0), etc.. it does successfully construct everything using my Mac camera.

Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: The issue was installing opencv4nodejs without having ffmpeg installed BEFORE. So i run again npm install and rebuild opencv that was now aware of FFMPEG and everything worked as was supposed to do. I can read from udp stream and forward video as i want to my front end

Comment: can you explain the method how you stream the Tello video. I am building a web app for it. stuck with the video streaming part

Comment: Sure @MohamedRaza !

Some time passed from this situation so i'm not remembering everything right but i ended up experimenting some ways

1 - using opencv4nodejs + ffmpeg i was able to pass the udp video stream coming from the drone to opencv method in node app connected to the drone that enabled me to convert the raw video to base64 frames that i sent to front end via websocket. 

2 i found a library for client side that enabled me to get raw h264 stream from drone and converting it in ancient mpeg1 video format or something like that directly in client

3 --> next comment

Comment: @MohamedRaza

3 - I used a more complex way using a node js based streaming server via rtsp protocol that was able to link to the drone video stream, and to forward hsl video format to front end. on front end i had a hsl client side converter that enabled me to watch the video stream.


Anyway, since this was a side project i could deidcate too much time on it and for this reson i didnt found a great solution. each of the three above were good for streaming  but the first latency was high probably due to the conversion from raw h264 to hls.
Hope to have been helpful, Man

Comment: I still have the BE and FE of the project but i think there is no streaming part in there dont remember though what remained there.

https://github.com/MarcoTerzoloGit/drone-tello-backend

https://github.com/MarcoTerzoloGit/drone-tello-frontend

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-media-server. (this is the key for succeding in understanding how to handle the stream, in my case is what helped me most)

Comment: <video id="video"></video>
<script>

  setTimeout(() => {
   renderPlayer();
  }, 5000)

  function renderPlayer() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var videoSrc = 'http://demo.unified-streaming.com/video/tears-of-steel/tears-of-steel.ism/.m3u8' /* 'http://localhost:8000/live/drone/index.m3u8' */;
    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      var hls = new Hls();
      hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
      hls.attachMedia(video);
      hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function() {
        video.play();
      });
    }
  }
</script>

Comment: IN the comment above there is what remained about my latest test. if u change the url with the commented ocalhost you cant est the FE and your node media stream that in. this case was open on port 8000